# How to say "I hope to be back in Japan sometime next year"

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I'm very much a beginner so I'm still learning grammar, but I want to translate "I hope to be back in Japan sometime next year".

> 日本にかえりたい来年といいですね
> nippon ni kaeritai rainen to ii desu ne

Is this correct? Or is there a better way to translate this?

Answer (score 3):

The time comes at the start of the sentence. Also, instead of using ～たい (want), in this case it's better to use a potential form with といいですね.  Finally, 帰る is usually only used by native Japanese as Japan is their home country. For foreigners, 戻る is a bit more natural, as you are returning to Japan rather than going back to your home country. I guess you could argue that 帰る can be used by foreigners who are permanent residents in Japan, but I still prefer 戻る.
So here is one possible translation:

来年日本に戻れるといいですね。(I hope I am able to return to Japan next year.)

Comment: Your explanation on how to use "日本に戻る" and "日本に帰る" for "to return to Japan" is very good.

Comment: Is `Finally, 帰る is usually only used by native Japanese as Japan is their home country` really accurate?  / My sense is that it makes sense to use when referring to the country where you *reside* (書いてある説明は国籍に基づいて、事実は居住国ではないか).

Comment: `来年日本に戻れるといいですね。` -- って聞くと "I hope **YOU** can return to Japan next year" って意味だと思ってしまうのは私だけでしょうか・・・

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you visited Japan and want to be back there, that sentence is a little awkward, because as already pointed out, かえる is something like going back to the homeland.
The earlier answer is actually a grammatically natural sentence and arguably understandable to native people, but Aするといいですね is generally used to hope that **some other person** does A, which makes them feel this sentence weird.
The more natural translation would be like "来年また日本に行きたいです。"

Comment: I thought she felt nostalgic, saudade feel. So, she said かえりたい.